# SSH Connection Timed Out

Tags: windows, ssh, raspberry-pi, openssh

I have an SSH server running on my Raspberry Pi at home, and I'am trying to connect from school network on a Windows 10 machine. Note that I installed the OpenSSH binaries on github, which are labeled for Windows 7, but I do not think that would be relevant. Whenever I try to ssh into my RPi from school, it times out.

```
PS C:\Program Files\OpenSSH-Win64> ./ssh -v pi@184.bbb.ccc.ddd
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: Connecting to 184.bbb.ccc.ddd [184.bbb.ccc.ddd] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 184.bbb.ccc.ddd port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 184.bbb.ccc.ddd port 22: Connection timed out
```

Pinging works fine:

```
PS C:\Program Files\OpenSSH-Win64> ping 184.bbb.ccc.ddd
Pinging 184.bbb.ccc.ddd with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 184.bbb.ccc.ddd: bytes=32 time=77ms TTL=57
Reply from 184.bbb.ccc.ddd: bytes=32 time=76ms TTL=57
Reply from 184.bbb.ccc.ddd: bytes=32 time=76ms TTL=57
Reply from 184.bbb.ccc.ddd: bytes=32 time=75ms TTL=57
Ping statistics for 184.bbb.ccc.ddd:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 75ms, Maximum = 77ms, Average = 76ms
```

Server side, the output of `grep sshd /var/log/auth.log` doesn't show that anything tried to connect. I can ssh from my phone perfectly fine, so I think it must be something on the school network side. I checked firewall rules in windows. Curiously, I **was** able to connect using the same command above, **once**. And it happened randomly, like the fifth try or something. Every other try since then has been timing out.

Comment: Ah 0.0.0.0 was a placeholder. I failed to change it in the ping output. Good thing I changed the default rpi password. Thanks for telling me. I enter the 184 address when trying to ssh. @Kamil Maciorowski